# kill forms authentication session after inactivity

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have an asp.net mvc 4 application that uses forms authentication.

I want to set a time limit of 30 mins of the site where if a logged in person is inactive for this period of time (not the time since login), they are automatically logged out. I am persisting to cookies at present and do not have session state.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're using cookies, won't setting the cookie expiry to 30 minutes after the last access be sufficient?

Comment: Can this be done with forms auth cookie? How can I ask?

Comment: Should be. Hmm. I normally do this, but I kinda feel that there's a much easier way to do it than how I generally do, but I'll try to fashion a bit of code as an answer.

Comment: How are you using the FormsAuthentication class?  If you're using the default, you need only set the timeout in the web.config and the FormsAuthentication class will use it.  If, however, you are creating a custom ticket, then you will have to set the timeouts manually by setting the properties of the ticket and cookie.

Comment: Thanks for this however I would like the time period be based on inactivity and not based on from time they first login. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: have you tried slidingExpiration?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define an expiry date on your Forms Authentication cookie so that it expires within 30 minutes of its creation (presumably when an access to your app has been made).

I generally do this by first creating a `FormsAuthenticationTicket`:

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket {
    1,  // a version number; do with it as you like
    "my ticket name",
    DateTime.Now,   // set when the cookie is valid from
    DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout), // and when it expires
    false,  // is the cookie persistent?
    "cookie data"  // the actual "value" of the cookie;
                   // I normally put in sufficient stuff to recreate
                   // the principal + identity on request
};

// encrypt that
var token = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
```

Then you can move forward to actually creating the cookie

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, token) {
    // expiry, again (there must be something redundant here)
    Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
    // add this if you need it
    HttpOnly = true
};

// then flush that in with the response
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

The value of `FormsAuthentication.Timeout` can either be defined in your `web.config`, or set in your code somewhere. The default is 30 minutes, so if you didn't change anything up, you should be fine.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms timeout="30" ... >
            <!-- ... -->
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

I feel that there should be an easier way to do this, but I like doing it the way above for the (relatively) fine-grained detail. That, or I'm just being unnecessarily ignorant.

Depending on my app's needs, I can add additional validation to the authentication ticket by crafting a class specifically meant to be passed in as a sort of DTO to the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. There's quite a bit of flexibility here for you to leverage on.

Comment: Thanks for this however I would like the time period be based on inactivity and not based on from time they first login. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: If by inactivity, you mean server calls, then update the cookie every time they send in a request. If by inactivity you mean like moving the mouse pointer, then that's a whole different banana.

Answer (score 0):

Why Confuse with cookies? Simply setting timeout should do the job

Something like below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Test/LogOn" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/Test/Index" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thanks for this however I would like the time period be based on inactivity and not based on from time they first login. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: timeout only happens when the user is inactive of 30 mins. Not after 30 mins of login time. So this should work. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The solution I suggest is to utilize the "slidingExpiration" property of FormsAuth:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Also, to create a persistent cookie, on Login():

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
```

This way, you will have a sliding window of 20 minutes of inactivity, meaning that, each action the user makes will move the expiration window forward for another 20 min. So, if truly inactive for 20 minutes, the cookie will expire.